# custom client validation in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm writing custom client validation in MVC 4 and set a break point in Firebug.
This line has a problem:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterthanattrebutedate", function (value, element, param) {
    return Date.parse(value) > Date.parse($(param).val());
});
```

After the first line, it does not go to the return line. In the first line d is undefined.

```
public string OtherPrpertyName { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
 { 
var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule(); 
rule.ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()); 
rule.ValidationType = "greaterthanattrebutedate"; rule.ValidationParameters.Add("other",OtherPrpertyName); 
yield return rule; 
}
```

jquery code

```
    /// <reference path="jquery-1.6.2-vsdoc.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate-vsdoc.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" />
$(document).ready(function () {   
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterthanattrebutedate", function (value, element, param) {
//        debugger;
        return Date.parse(value) > Date.parse($(param).val());
});
});
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("greaterthanattrebutedate", ["other"], function (options) {
        options.rules["greaterthanattrebutedate"] = "#" + options.params.other;
        options.messages["greaterthanattrebutedate"] = options.message;
    });
```

Comment: nothing is clear from your question. Putup more information. What is d?

Comment: unfortunately I do not know what is d. in firebug write d is undefined . I think my first line has a problem.I search in internet and i assure that first line syntax is correct but i do not know why after first line,  dose not go to the second line.
and also check all of setting and are ok like webconfig - call class ...

Comment: my sample exactly like a pluralsight sample.
and in the movie work correctly but in my program dose not work and several time check my code and pluralsight sample is in MVC 3 but my MVC is 4.

Comment: Then it is some variable from JQuery minified file. You are passing some value that JQuery is using in its one of the function and there it is not getting the satisfied value.

Comment: what is it that you are passing to element? is it a valid element?

Comment: the code you put here is not readable, insted put in your original question as update.